# Arrow box aligment

Tags: vertical-alignment, nodes, arrows, tikz-shape

I have to align vertically "arrow boxes" in the picture below?
So I have two questions:

1. How to read "inner sep" register value and bounding as well connecting lines thickness register values of applied styles?
2. Is there any method of global adjusting of the distance beetween tip of arrow in "arrow box" and the edge of the pointed line?

[image: result of code execution]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}            %| for arangement objects on layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}                %|
\pgfsetlayers{background,myback,main}   %|

\begin{document}
\def\mtw{3.0}       % box width
\def\pal{2.5}       % perturbation arrow length
\def\ptw{4.0}       % side box width

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    line join=round,
    every node/.style={font=\footnotesize,align=center},
    process/.style={text width=\mtw cm,fill=white,draw},
    perturbation/.style={draw,right=1pt,arrow box,arrow box arrows={west:\pal cm},thin,text width=\ptw cm},
    node distance=8ex,
    flux/.style={very thick,-{Stealth[flex=1.2]}}
    ]

    \node (n1) at (0,0) [anchor=south,process] {initial conditions};
    \node (n2) [below=of n1,process] {first stage of the process};
    \pgfmathparse{(\pal cm-0.5*\mtw cm)}        % shorter arrow length
    %\pgfmathparse{(\pal cm-0.5*\mtw cm-0.3333em)}  % shorter arrow length; 0.3333em is "inner sep" value
    %\pgfmathparse{(\pal cm-0.5*\mtw cm-\mydist cm)}    % shorter arrow length; how to put into \mydist "inner sep" and line widths?
    \edef\pas{\pgfmathresult pt}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
        \node [perturbation,right=1pt of n1.east,arrow box arrows={west:\pas}]
              {perturbations of initial conditions};
        \draw [flux] (n1) -- (n2)
              node [midway,perturbation] {perturbations of external conditions};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Considering https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235697/how-to-get-line-width-and-inner-sep-values, I suppose you found the answer for the first of your questions. For the second, I don't actually understand exactly what you mean, are you after the `arrow box head extend` and `arrow box tip angle` keys? (See manual for description.)